# Keyword query in elasticsearch on multiple fields

Tags: jquery, mysql, elasticsearch

I have the following data structure:

```
{
  "_index" : "news_current",
  "_type" : "dc",
  "_id" : "52265dafed5e6328a36253ac2575b891",
  "_score" : 0.3308331,
  "_source":{"_drupal_url": "http://www.bild.de/politik/inland/margot-kaessmann/bei-hitler-vergeht-mir-das-lachen-43132712.bild.html", "_drupal_source": "bild.de", "_drupal_type": "dc",  "_drupal_date": "2015-10-24T23:44:30+02:00", "2015-10-24T22:03:04", "_drupal_content": "TEXT CONTENT", "_drupal_id": "52265dafed5e6328a36253ac2575b891", "_drupal_title": "Margot K\u00e4\u00dfmann: Bei Adolf Hitler vergeht mir das Lachen"}
}
```

From this I would like to compute scores for two fields ("_drupal_title" and "_drupal_content") using the elasticsearch "string_query". 
I can do it seperately by doing the following:

```
{
 "query": {
   "query_string": {
                    "default_field" : "_drupal_title",
                    "query": "KEYWORD"
                   }
 }
```

Does anyone have an idea how to get scores for both fields in one query (I thought of an OR like logic with scores output when the keyword shows up in title or content)

Comment: Do you want combined scores or separate score for each field?

Comment: Separately, for combined scores there is something like multi-field I believe

Comment: Do you think this is possible in elasticsearch or should I better make a workaround  from the seperate outputs?

Comment: I don't think it's possible to get scores at field level, that said you can give boost to individual fields using multimatch. see this: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/5.5/query-dsl-multi-match-query.html#_literal_fields_literal_and_per_field_boosting